# Unable to add a timeout in this node http get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have this code, where the function `download` should be called each 5 seconds, but it doesn't seem to work, since all the images are downloaded at the same time.

```js
const download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
  request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback); 
   });
};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    download(
      'https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/image', 
      `images/image${i}.jpg`,
      function () {
        console.log('done');
      });
    },
    5000
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` function is hard-coded with `5000`. This means your loop is running from 0 to 99 and setting up 100 timeouts, each with a wait time of 5000. Since the loop is executed very quickly, the timeouts that get made also execute very close together.

You need something like:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   ...
   },
   5000 * i
 )
```

This will spread the timeouts out from 0 * 5000 to 99 * 5000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

The way synchronous code executes is that all your code has to finish running before anything can be updated or "rendered" to the screen. So the for loop will run until it's done, then the screen will update, but it will of course only have the final view of the executed code to render.

To fix this inside each iteration of the for loop you should fire an asynchronous function that will update at a later and later time, outside of the current synchronous for loop code.

for example:

```js
    const download = function () {
        return "ready player "
    };

 for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {//the code will only iterate 10 times
    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(download()+i);
     }, 500 * i);  //reduced the timer here to 500
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `setInterval` to repeat your method:

```
const download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
  request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback); 
   });
};

setInterval(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        download(
          'https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/image', 
          `images/image${i}.jpg`,
          function () {
            console.log('done');
        });
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please do not do this. This will download 100 images every five seconds until the end of time. If you are going to use `setInterval` you need to save the ID of the interval in a variable and then later use `clearInterval` to cancel it when it should stop.

Comment: The requirement was "where the function download should be called each 5 seconds" - it doesn't mention anything about a limit. Maybe I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: In reading the original code it seemed to me that the intent was to download a finite number of images (100), one every five seconds. That way the requests aren't flooding the web server. With your code, you will definitely be flooding the web server with requests and there is no limit to how long your code will run. You would have to manually kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I used `.then()` to fix it.

```
const download = require("image-downloader");

function downloadIMG(opts) {
  const { filename, image } = download
    .image(opts)
    .then(({ filename }) => {
      console.log("Saved to", filename); // saved to /path/to/dest/photo
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```